# How do I simulate multiple pop3, imap and SMTP connections?

Tags: imap, smtp, pop3

I need to test at what point does the mail server stop responding and am hence looking for a tool I can use on Windows and *Nix that will allow me to simulate multiple connections. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could cobble up something running several `nc` (netcat, from [nmap](http://nmap.org)) in parallel.

Comment: Is there an example I could follow?